# Ignore files on capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a problem when i deploy application using capistrano. Even if my `sitemap.xml` and `robots.txt` are written in `.gitignore` file, after deploy, that files are destroyed. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that the files are deleted from server after cap deploy?

Comment: The problem is when i deploy app to server, it pushs those files too, replacing previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could understand those files are specific to the environment and should persist across deployments.

To address your issue you should store them into `shared` directory as explained [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/).

Then set them up into your deploy config file `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :linked_files, ["robots.txt", "sitemap.xml"]
```

Or if you are using capistrano 3.5 or above:

```
append :linked_files, "robots.txt", "sitemap.xml"
```